# Foreach limit to word

Tags: php, foreach, limit

Im new here , looking for solution for this part of code to just make loop when title is = style or colour .

```
  foreach ($pp_fileds as $f) {

                    if ( !empty($f['title']) and !empty($f["id"]) and array_key_exists("owlabpfl_".$f["id"] , $owlabpfl_meta) ){
                        echo '
                        <li>
                            <div class="list-label">'.__($f['title'],'toranj').'</div>
                            <div class="list-des">'.$owlabpfl_meta["owlabpfl_".$f["id"]][0].'</div><div class="list-des"><img src="http://factorymarco.ie/assets/'.__($f['title'],'toranj').'/'.$owlabpfl_meta["owlabpfl_".$f["id"]][0].'.jpg" alt="'.$owlabpfl_meta["owlabpfl_".$f["id"]][0].'"></div>
                        </li>
                        ';
                    }

            }
```

Comment: You can use `strpos();` function to compare two strings.

Comment: `strpos($f['title'], "style or colour")`